# Calling a method from controller using AJAX not working after publishing the web application

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The Ajax calling returns the status code 500 on server, but works fine locally. 
Kindly help me to solve this issue.

```
<script>
var SendEmail = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",                                                
        url: '@Url.Action("SendMailToUser", "Home")',                      
        success: function () {
            alert("Mail sent successfully!");
        },                      
        failure: function(returnData)
        {
            console.debug(returnData); 
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

EDIT 1:

Here, I have included the Controller method too. Am I missing anything in the controller?

```
public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application GetActiveOutlookApplication()
    {
        return (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
    }

    public void SendMailToUser()
    {                     
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
            mail.Subject = "Test mail";
            Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = app.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser user = currentUser.GetExchangeUser();
                // Add recipient using display name, alias, or smtp address
                mail.Recipients.Add(user.PrimarySmtpAddress);
                mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                mail.Attachments.Add(@"File location", Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                mail.Send();
            }              
   }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console

Comment: What makes you think it "fails"? What are you seeing? Is there an error message? Error dump? console log?

Comment: under success in the ajax call put ", failure: function(returnData){ console.debug(returnData); }". Also can you attach the debugger to the site?

Comment: I get the alert message as "Mail sent successfully" and an error message in the console as "XML Parsing Error: no element found".

Comment: It's successful hitting the action and returning successful with errors. Your problem is to do with your action in the controller. I'm assuming you are passing XML to the email service at some point and this is your issue.

Comment: I have added the method from the controller above. Is there anything to be changed in the content. Kindly suggest!

Comment: You may need to install office on the machine you are deploying this too.

Comment: Modify your question to describe *how* it's not working. And get rid of that empty catch block - that's just going to hide errors in your code.

Comment: The question was modified for clarity. I get the status code 500 on server. Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this its will works.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SendMailToUser", "Home")',    
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.d);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: add **HttpVerbs**  above the method `[HttpPost]`

Comment: I get the status code 500 when published on server.